# The Probability of Rolling the Same Number with 10 Dice That Have 19 Sides

Tags: probability, dice

I like dice and I want to know what the probability is for rolling the same number with 10 dice that have 19 sides.  Also, do these dice exist or not?

Comment: I really probably don't know the answer to this.

Comment: would you know the answer if it was two dice?

Comment: Maybe I would, and maybe I can!  Oh, wait!  I can!  The probability is 1/19!

Comment: I've finally earned the "comment everywhere" privilege!  Also, user111236, you're right about it.  For the first die, there should be a one and for the second die, there should be a 1/19.  Therefore, the probability is 1*1/19=1/19.

Answer (score 3):

You are rolling $10$ dice each with $19$ sides.

The first die can land on anything, but then all of the rest have to land on that same number.

The chance that each die lands on this number is $\frac{1}{19}$ since they have 19 sides. And since our rolls are independent, this means we have a probability of

$$\frac{1}{19^{9}}$$

to roll the same number on every die.

Comment: 1/19^2 or 1/361 is approximately equal to 0.00277 and how did you write that fraction like that?  Maybe with something like tools or another computer thing?

Comment: It is called latex. Click to edit my post and you will see how exactly it is typed, or google latex, very useful.

Comment: A primer on writing math on this site is [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto)

Answer (score 1):

The probability of rolling 10 dice on the same number with 19 sides is 1*1/19*1/19*1/19*1/19*1/19*1/19*1/19*1/19*1/19, or 1/322,687,697,779 because the first die can land on any number from 1 to 19, but the other dice have to match the number on the first die.

Comment: As you see, that's an answer typed in by me, user111236 and I hope it's right.

Comment: Also, I think the answer at the very top goes with that question.

Comment: $19^9$ _does_ equal 322,687,697,779, so it's extremely, extremely unlikely that you'll roll 10 dice with 19 sides with the same number.